# Not getting response when inputting a choice

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
print ('Hey Lets play rock paper scissor ')
number_of_tries= 0
while number_of_tries < 5:
    option= ['rock','paper','scissor']
    hand= random.choice((option))
    dash= str(input("whats your pick ")).lower()
    number_of_tries += 1
    if dash not in option:
        print('not a vaid option')
    elif dash == "rock":
        if hand== 'paper':
            print(f'you lost, the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand== dash:
            print(f'its a tie the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand== "sicssor":
            print(f'you win the computer selected {hand}')
            break
    elif dash == "scissor":
        if hand== "rock":
            print(f'you loose the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand== "scissor":
            print(f'its a tie the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand== "paper":
            print(f'you win the computer selected {hand}')
            break         
    elif dash == "paper":
        if hand== "sicssor":
            print(f'you lost the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand== "paper":
            print(f'its a tie the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand== "rock":
            print(f'you win the computer selected {hand}')
            break `enter code here`
print("the end")
```

Not getting response when inputting a choice tried rock 3 times got answer on 1 and got looped twice not sure what I am missing. Not sure why it keeps asking for more detail when trying to post question

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo that's repeated a few times:

```
    elif dash == "rock":
        if hand== 'paper':
            print(f'you lost, the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand== dash:
            print(f'its a tie the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand== "sicssor":  # oops
            print(f'you win the computer selected {hand}')
            break
```

One way to avoid bugs like this is to use `if...elif...else` and raise an error in the `else`:

```
    elif dash == "rock":
        if hand == 'paper':
            print(f'you lost, the computer selected {hand}')
        elif hand == dash:
            print(f'its a tie the computer selected {hand}')
        elif hand== "sicssor":
            print(f'you win the computer selected {hand}')
            break
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"unhandled computer selection {hand}")
```

With this change you'd see that `scissor` raised an error, which would immediately lead you to double-check your `scissor` check and you'd see the typo.

Another option is to use constants, e.g.:

```
ROCK = 'rock'
SCISSOR = 'scissor'
PAPER = 'paper'
```

and then use those constants in your code instead of the actual strings:

```
    elif dash == ROCK:
        if hand == PAPER:
            print(f'you lost, the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand == dash:
            print(f'its a tie the computer selected {hand}')
        if hand == SICSSOR:
            print(f'you win the computer selected {hand}')
            break
```

Here you'll get an error because the variable `SICSSOR` hasn't been defined, which again will quickly lead you to be able to fix your bug.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know  raise ValueError function, I will be using it from now on